# Download colab notebook from itself

Tags: python, download, google-colaboratory, ipynb

Is there a way to download the google colab notebook from one of its cells?

The issue appears when co-working on the same notebook and one accidentally overwrites the output of another. I want to save the *ipynb* file automatically after running my cells.

I'm aware of the way to download a file that was created by the notebook:

```py
from google.colab import files
files.download('example_file.csv')
```

But I couldn't locate where the notebook's *ipynb* is placed in the filesystem outside the *content* directory.